# mysqldb query: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql

```
curs.execute ("INSERT INTO temperatur (datum, uhrzeit, ort, messwert) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), %s, %s);" % ort, messwert)
```

drops out this->

```
    curs.execute ("INSERT INTO temperatur (datum, uhrzeit, ort, messwert) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), %s, %s);" % ort, messwert)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

why is this not working?

Comment: Don't use string formatting to create SQL queries; it's an unnecessary injection risk, let the engine do it for you. In this case, the problem is simply that `messwert` is a second parameter to `execute`, not a second value to be formatted into the string.

Comment: is this `pymysql`?

Comment: Never perform parameter formatting in SQL yourself, it makes it *very* vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: its MySQLdb. how does the engine this for me?

Comment: @KaiH.: also see [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](//stackoverflow.com/q/775296)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use string formatting, you are exposing yourself to SQL injection.

Pass in your arguments as a *sequence* in the second argument:

```
curs.execute(
    "INSERT INTO temperatur (datum, uhrzeit, ort, messwert) "
    "VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), %s, %s)",
    (ort, messwert))
```

Here `(ord, messwert)` is a tuple passed in as the second argument to `curs.execute()`. You don't need the `;` in the SQL statement.

You got the error because you only passed *one* value to the `%` string format, the expression you used is `"string value" % ort`, as `messwert` was being passed in as the second argument to `curs.execute()`. You'd have to use `"string value" % (ord, messwert)` instead. However, you should *avoid* using string formatting altogether however, as that leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks where an attacker makes use of the lack of proper escaping applied to the values interpolated into the SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is right that you shouldn't use string formatting, but the quick answer for you is just that you need parentheses containing your tuple, i.e., `%(ort, messwert)`